# Efforts or effort

Tags: differences

Which of the below sentences is more appealing?

> 1. He makes repeated efforts to overcome obstacles.
> 2. He makes repeated effort to overcome obstacles.

Comment: #1 sees each attempt as an individual ‘effort’ while #2 sees the whole sequence of repetitions as a single effort.

Answer (score 1):

I think that, if it is repeated, then it should not remain singular.
'He makes repeated efforts,' therefore.

Or, 'he repeatedly makes an effort', would be good.

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/effort
But, technically, it seems that the word 'effort' can mean either the energy exerted or the actual exertions themselves, so it appears that neither of the statements in the question is actually wrong, as such.